# What is the Liquid template code for "X days from today" where "X" is the number of days between today and the next Monday?

Tags: datetime, liquid

I live in NYC and I believe that for me it should be something like

```
{{ now | in_time_zone: 'America/New_York' | advance_date_to_next: 'Monday' | blah blah blah }}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the [date filter](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/additional-filters#date). A day is 86400 seconds. Example to add 3 days from now:

```
{% assign days = 3 | times: 86400 %}
{{ "now" | date: "%s" | plus: days | date: "%Y, %m, %-d %Z" }}
```

Note: You need the `date: "%s"` filter applied first to `"now"` for Liquid to understand that you are using the current timestamp and not the string "now".

In the [output date formatting](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) `%Z` is the time zone.

It's not completely what you are asking for, but you can do the liquid arithmetic...or use something like [DateJs](http://www.datejs.com/) on the frontend :)

Comment: Thanks, @jrbedard, I'll give this a try!